# How to use the phrase "looks like"?

Tags: phrases, phrasal-verbs, philosophy

Does the phrase "looks like" can mean that two objects are the same? For example if I say "This car looks like John's car" and the car is indeed John's car am I lying?

Comment: The car could be John's or it couldn't be. Don't blame yourself in either case.

Comment: @Stockfish I just wanted to make clear the difference. Does similar implies not equal?

Comment: Good spot. "This car looks like John's car" can mean _either_ "This car looks as if it must be John's car" **_or_** "This car looks [very] similar to John's car". Deletion (here from "This car looks like it must be John's car"  **_or_** "This car looks like John's car does" ** often gives rise to ambiguity. But deletions are often used, usually where the ambiguity is resolved by context.

Comment: You can only be lying if it *doesn't* ***look*** like John's car. The car can look like John's *and be* John's, or look like John's but *not actually be* John's. In either case, the only thing that's being evaluated for truthfulness on your part is that it looks like John's.

Comment: @JasonBassford This clears some of my confusion.Does  A "looks like" B we mean that there is at least one common characteristic or that A and B have some common characteristcs but don't have all their characteristics are equal?

Comment: Your question is not, in my opinion, suitable for this site, but could be asked on [ell.se].

Comment: There is a Gricean implicature here. Based on [the Maxim of Quality](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/188085/15299), if you are saying something looks like something else, then that's all you can say about it. If you know in addition that it is identical, then you're violating the Maxim of Quantity by not making your contribution as informative as is required. In other words, you're lying by not telling the whole truth.